# EF6 Create one way navigation in db with two schemas

Tags: ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

We have two tables in the same database but in different schemas.
i.e. foo.Table1 and bar.Table1 both with an Id column as primary key.

foo.Table1 is from an existing model, cannot be modified and is already in the database.

We want to create an ef6 code first model of bar.Table1 that will have its primary key (bar.Table1.Id) set as a foreign key of foo.Table1.Id. We have already accomplished it in SMSS but we cannot figure out how to do it in code without affecting foo.Table1. 
Thank you

Comment: You have done it in SSMS, I assume you mean that the database schema has been modified as required, so how would you still affect `foo.Table1`?

Comment: I mean that I have created the relation in SSMS in order to check if this is feasible (between two different schemas) but I don't know how to implement it in code so as to get it in the migration script on the next Add-Migration